# owasp sensitive data prevention in java

Tags: java, owasp

owasp sensitive data prevention in java

In my code I wrote following line and got A6-Sensitive Data Exposure- Heap Inspection

private String password;

How should I change this code for owasp sensitive data prevention in java?

Comment: Where did you get "A6-Sensitive Data Exposure- Heap Inspection"? Which tool are you using?

Comment: I am using jenkins to get the scan report for owasp sensitive data exposure.

Comment: Jenkins is just a build server - Which plugin or checking tool did you give this message?

Comment: OWASP Dependency-Check Plugin

Comment: Sorry checkmarx is the plugin we are using for generating the report not the dependency check plugin

Answer (score 0):

Still not clear which tool gave you this warning at this line (it is unlikely that it was the dependency check). I can only guess the tool wants passwords to be stored in a `char[]` rather than a `String`.

The reasoning is that you can overwrite the password with blanks if it is no longer needed and therefore minimise the chance that it shows up in heap dumps.

Comment: it is checkmarx tool not the dependency check tool.